# Is the ASP.Net Cache shared between different user sessions?

Tags: asp.net, caching

In a page if I do the following:

> Cache["key"] = myObject;

Is that cached object available for requests that are for other users?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Yes.  The cache is Application level, and all users are in the same application.

If you need a per-user Cache you could use the Session, but that's not quite the same.  The cache allows the framework to automatically expire items in a different way from the session.  If you want the cache behavior on a per-user basis (not necessarily a good idea) you could build the user's ID into part of your key for the main cache.

Answer (score 10):

Yes it is available for all users on the same server. However, if you are running a farm, it will only be available to users that are using the server in which the data was added to cache.

Comment: On the same server AND on the same APPLICATION

Answer (score 2):

Cache is good for per AppDomain. The single application like web Applicaiton usually remain in the single AppDomain. But cache can not be shared between something like web app and web service.